# Accessing tuple values in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

```
q = "cats dogs"

d = {'cats': {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'nuts': {3: 1}, 'egg': {5: 1, 6: 2}, 'dogs': {1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 4}, 'idea': {4: 1}, 'frog': {2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}

newList = []

for word in q:
   for x,y in d.values():
       newList.append(d[word].x())
```

What I'm attempting to do here is get each first part of the number pairs and put into the list when it corresponds to a word in q. So I'm expecting newList to be [1,2,3,4,1,2,3].

I am getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). How should I be doing this?

Comment: Try printing `word` in that loop. You will be surprised.

Comment: And you might want to replace `x,y` with `item` and then also print `item`. You will be surprised again.

Comment: Yikes! Was not expecting that at all

Comment: Do the values in your dictionary actually have methods that are their keys? As this: `d[word].x()` would suggest that.

Comment: I don't follow. I thought I'd be able to retrieve all the first parts of the numbers for a given key by doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the dictionary 'd' are actually of type dictionary themselves, not tuples. I think you may want to reorganize this a bit.

```
for word in q.split(" "):
  if word in d:
    child_dict = d[word]
    for key in child_dict:
      newList.append(key)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Brain is very fried today. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
q = "cats dogs"

d = {'cats': {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'nuts': {3: 1}, 'egg': {5: 1, 6: 2}, 'dogs': {1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 4}, 'idea': {4: 1}, 'frog': {2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}

newList = []

for word in q.split(' '):
    newList.extend(list(d[word].keys()))

print(newList)
```

It prints out `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
q = "cats dogs"

d = {'cats': {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'nuts': {3: 1}, 'egg': {5: 1, 6: 2}, 'dogs': {1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 4}, 'idea': {4: 1}, 'frog': {2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}

newList = []    

for word in q.split(' '):
    if word in d:
        newList.extend([i for i in d[word]])

print(newList)
```